# String List always null

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize a list of strings as private static final but  I always get the value of `l` as null, and if I declare it as shown in the second snippet of code it works.

What I'm trying to do is add the elements of a list I declare to a trie to match some pattern later...

Any thoughts on why the null value in the first example and how can I correct it? Thanks

```
public class Myclass {
    public static final Myclass INSTANCE = new Myclass();

    private static final List<String> l = Arrays.asList("ofo", "oof", "foo");

    private Trie trie;

    private Myclass() {
        trie = buildTrie();
    }

    private Trie buildTrie() {
        TrieBuilder builder = Trie.builder();
        Iterator<String> iterator = l.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            builder.addKeyword(iterator.next());
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

```
public class Myclass {
    public static final Myclass INSTANCE = new Myclass();
    private Trie trie;

    private Myclass() {
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList("ofo", "oof", "foo");
        trie = buildTrie();
    }

    private Trie buildTrie() {
        TrieBuilder builder = Trie.builder();
        Iterator<String> iterator = l.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            builder.addKeyword(iterator.next());
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second case, `l` isn't in scope in `buildTrie()`, so it simply won't compile.

Comment: @khelwood  Done ! Thanks

Comment: As an aside, using an enhanced for loop would be much easier than Iterator.

Comment: it works for the second case , my problem is with the first case where list l is always null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Myclass {
    public static final Myclass INSTANCE = new Myclass();

    private static final List<String> l = Arrays.asList("ofo", "oof", "foo");
```

Static initialization is done in the order of declaration. This means that `INSTANCE` is initialized before `l`, so the constructor of `Myclass` reads the uninitialized value of `l`.

Reverse the order of the declarations:

```
public class Myclass {
    private static final List<String> l = Arrays.asList("ofo", "oof", "foo");

    public static final Myclass INSTANCE = new Myclass();
```

Or, if you don't actually require `l` otherwise, consider passing it as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Thanks Andy ! as for your last comment , you recommend using a for loop instead of Iterator ? ( in a more complex example or large data )

Comment: @Slach enhanced for loops use an iterator internally. It's just cleaner syntax.